# Make opied values from not visible list visible [Sharepoint 2013]

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, workflow, lookup

I have a list A with various columns. One of them is a lookup from another list B.

List A:

```
Name | Option copied | Option lookup
```

The read permissions for list B are on item level. Reason is that for the 'new entry' form of list A, only options 1-3 should be selectable. (However, there are other options 4-6 to be set only by a small group of people.)

List B:

```
Option | Read Permission
-------|----------------
1      | all
2      | all
3      | all
4      | some
5      | some
6      | some
```

Now I want to show all entries of list A. Not only those with option 1-3 but also with option 4-6.

List A:

```
Name | Option copied | Option lookup from B
-----|---------------|---------------------
A    | 1             | 1
B    | 2             | 2
C    | 5             | 5
```

Therefore, I created a workflow to copy the lookup value to another column in list A (works fine).

Problem is: Only entries with options 1-3 are shown.

List A:

```
Name | Option copied | Option lookup from B
-----|---------------|---------------------
A    | 1             | 1
B    | 2             | 2
```

So the question is:

**How can I still have the read permissions on list B, but show all entries (including the copied lookup from list B) in list A?**

Comment: Why are you down-voting the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be not possible, due to permissions inheritance or so.

I gave up and implemented another solution. :-(

Why are you down-voting the question?